# MKAnnotation View Segue

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I have an array of places that I am displaying on a MapView. I have created a MKAnnotationView to display a right button. I am then displaying a detailView and passing data through the segue but it is displaying the wrong place. I believe there is an issue with my selectedAnnotations. The user will only be able to select one annotation at any one time.

Entire Class

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class MapViewController: UIViewController, PlacesModelDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    var places = [Place]()
    var model:PlacesModel?
    var locationManager:CLLocationManager?
    var lastKnownLocation:CLLocation?

    var selectedAnnotation: Place?

    // MARK: - Lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mapView.delegate = self

        // Set map properties
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true

        // Instantiate location manager
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager?.delegate = self

        // Instantiate places model if it is nil
        if model == nil {
            model = PlacesModel()
            model?.delegate = self
        }

        // Call get places
        model?.getPlaces()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Functions

    func plotPins() {

        var pinsArray = [MKPointAnnotation]()

        // Go through the array of places and plot them
        for p in places {

            // Create a pin
            let pin = MKPointAnnotation()

            // Set its properties
            pin.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(p.lat), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(p.long))
            pin.title = p.name
            pin.subtitle = p.getTypeName()

            // Add it to the map
            mapView.addAnnotation(pin)

            // Store the pin in the pinsArray
            pinsArray.append(pin)
        }

        // Center the map
        mapView.showAnnotations(pinsArray, animated: true)
    }

    func displaySettingsPopup() {

        // Create alert controller
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Couldn't find your location",
                                                message: "Location Services is turned off on your device or the GuideBookApp doesn't have permission to find your location. Please check your Privacy settings to continue.",
                                                preferredStyle: .alert)

        // Create settings button action
        let settingsAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .default) { (alertAction) in

            if let appSettings = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {

                UIApplication.shared.open(appSettings, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)

            }
        }
        alertController.addAction(settingsAction)

        // Create cancel button action
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        // Show the alert
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    // MARK: - Button Handlers

    @IBAction func locationButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

        // Check if location services are enabled
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {

            // They're enabled, now check the authorization status
            let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

            if status == .authorizedAlways || status == .authorizedWhenInUse {

                // Has permission
                locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()

                // Center the map on last location
                if let actualLocation = lastKnownLocation {
                    mapView.setCenter(actualLocation.coordinate, animated: true)
                }
            }
            else if status == .denied || status == .restricted {

                // Doesn't have permission
                // Tell user to check settings
                displaySettingsPopup()
            }
            else if status == .notDetermined {

                // Ask the user for permission
                locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            }

        }
        else {
            // Locations services are turned off
            // Tell user to check settings
            displaySettingsPopup()
        }

    }

    // MARK: - PlacesModelDelegate Methods

    func placesModel(places: [Place]) {

        // Set places property
        self.places = places

        // Plot the pins
        plotPins()
    }

    // MARK: - CLLocationManagerDelegate Methods

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        let location = locations.last

        if let actualLocation = location {

            // Create a pin
            let pin = MKPointAnnotation()
            pin.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: actualLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: actualLocation.coordinate.longitude)

            // Center the map, only if it's the first time locating the user
            if lastKnownLocation == nil {
                mapView.setCenter(actualLocation.coordinate, animated: true)
            }

            // Save the pin
            lastKnownLocation = actualLocation
        }

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

        // See what the user has answered
        if status == .denied {

            // Tell user that this app doesn't have permission. They can change it in their settings
            displaySettingsPopup()
        }
        else if status == .authorizedWhenInUse || status == .authorizedAlways {

            // Permission granted
            locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
        }

    }

}

extension MapViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {


    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        let identifier = "marker"
        var view: MKMarkerAnnotationView

        view = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        view.canShowCallout = true
        view.calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 5)
        view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)

        return view
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "mapSegue", sender: view)

    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {


        let selectedRow = mapView.selectedAnnotations.endIndex

        let selectedPlace = places[selectedRow]

        let detailModel = DetailModel()
        detailModel.place = selectedPlace

        let detailVC = segue.destination as! VenueDetailViewController
        detailVC.model = detailModel

    } 
}
```

Places Model

```
import UIKit

protocol PlacesModelDelegate {

    func placesModel(places:[Place])

}

class PlacesModel: NSObject, FirebaseManagerDelegate {

    // Properties
    var delegate:PlacesModelDelegate?
    var firManager:FirebaseManager?

    func getPlaces() {

        // Get places from FirebaseManager
        if firManager == nil {
            firManager = FirebaseManager()
            firManager!.delegate = self
        }

        // Tell firebase manager to fetch places
        firManager!.getPlacesFromDatabase()
    }

    func checkDataVersion() {

        // Get version from FirebaseManager
        if firManager == nil {
            firManager = FirebaseManager()
            firManager!.delegate = self
        }

        firManager!.getVersionFromDatabase()
    }

    // MARK: - FirebaseManager Delegate Methods

    func firebaseManager(places: [Place]) {

        // Notify the delegate
        if let actualDelegate = delegate {
            actualDelegate.placesModel(places: places)
        }
    }

}
```

FirebaseManager

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

@objc protocol FirebaseManagerDelegate {

    @objc optional func firebaseManager(places:[Place])
    @objc optional func firebaseManager(metaDataFor place:Place)
    @objc optional func firebaseManager(imageName:String, imageData:Data)

}

class FirebaseManager: NSObject {

    // MARK: - Properties

    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
    var delegate:FirebaseManagerDelegate?

    // MARK: - Initializers

    override init() {

        // Initialize the database reference
        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        super.init()
    }


    // MARK: - Places Functions

    func getPlacesFromDatabase() {

        // Create an array to store all the places
        var allPlaces = [Place]()

        // Before we retrieve from Firebase, check cachemanager
        if let cachedPlacesDict = CacheManager.getPlacesFromCache() {

            // We have data in cache, parse that instead
            // Call function to parse places dictionary

            allPlaces = parsePlacesFrom(placesDict: cachedPlacesDict)

            // Now return the places array
            // Dispatch this code to be done on the main thread
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                // Notify the delegate
                if let actualDelegate = self.delegate {
                    actualDelegate.firebaseManager?(places: allPlaces)
                }
            } // End DispatchQueue

            return
        }


        // Retrieve the list of Places from the database
        ref.child("places").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in



            let placesDict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

            // See if data is actually present
            if let actualPlacesDict = placesDict {

                // We actually have a places dictionary

                // Before working with the data, save it into cache
                CacheManager.putPlacesIntoCache(data: actualPlacesDict)

                // Call function to parse places dictionary
                allPlaces = self.parsePlacesFrom(placesDict: actualPlacesDict)

                // Now return the places array
                // Dispatch this code to be done on the main thread
                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    // Notify the delegate
                    if let actualDelegate = self.delegate {
                        actualDelegate.firebaseManager?(places: allPlaces)
                    }
                } // End DispatchQueue
            }

        }) // End observeSingleEvent

    } // End getForYouFromDatabase



    // MARK: - Meta Functions

    func getMetaFromDatabase(place:Place) {

        // Before fetching from firebase, check cache
        if let cachedMetaDict = CacheManager.getMetaFromCache(placeId: place.id) {

            // Parse the meta data
            parseMetaFrom(metaDict: cachedMetaDict, place: place)

            // Notify the delegate the the meta data has been fetched
            // Dispatch this code to be done on the main thread
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                // Notify the delegate
                if let actualDelegate = self.delegate {
                    actualDelegate.firebaseManager?(metaDataFor: place)
                }
            } // End DispatchQueue

            return
        }

        ref.child("meta").child(place.id).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            // Get the dictionary from the snapshot
            if let metaDict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {

                // Save data into cache
                CacheManager.putMetaIntoCache(data: metaDict, placeId: place.id)

                // Parse firebase results
                self.parseMetaFrom(metaDict: metaDict, place: place)

                // Notify the delegate the the meta data has been fetched
                // Dispatch this code to be done on the main thread
                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    // Notify the delegate
                    if let actualDelegate = self.delegate {
                        actualDelegate.firebaseManager?(metaDataFor: place)
                    }
                } // End DispatchQueue

            }

        }) // End observeSingleEvent

    } // End getMetaFromDatabase

    func getImageFromDatabase(imageName:String) {

        // Get the image

        // Check cache first
        if let imageData = CacheManager.getImageFromCache(imageName: imageName) {

            // Notify the delegate on the main thread
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                // Notify the delegate
                if let actualDelegate = self.delegate {
                    actualDelegate.firebaseManager?(imageName: imageName, imageData: imageData)
                }
            } // End DispatchQueue

            return
        }

        // Create the storage and file path references
        let storage = FIRStorage.storage()
        let imagePathReference = storage.reference(withPath: imageName)

        // Download in memory with a maximum allowed size of 1MB (1 * 1024 * 1024 bytes)
        imagePathReference.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
            if error != nil {
                // Uh-oh, an error occurred!

            } else if data != nil {

                // Data for the image is returned

                // Save the image data into cache
                CacheManager.putImageIntoCache(data: data!, imageName: imageName)

                // Notify the delegate on the main thread
                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    // Notify the delegate
                    if let actualDelegate = self.delegate {
                        actualDelegate.firebaseManager?(imageName: imageName, imageData: data!)
                    }
                } // End DispatchQueue
            }
        }
    }

    func closeObserversForPlace(placeId:String) {

        // Remove observers from that place node
        ref.child("meta").child(placeId).removeAllObservers()
    }



    // MARK: - Version Functions

    func getVersionFromDatabase() {

        // Get the version from the database
        ref.child("version").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            let versionString = snapshot.value as? String

            if let databaseVersion = versionString {

                let cachedVersion = CacheManager.getVersionFromCache()

                if cachedVersion != nil {

                    // Compare the cached version number to the database version
                    if databaseVersion > cachedVersion! {

                        // Remove all cached data
                        CacheManager.removeAllCachedData()
                        CacheManager.putVersionIntoCache(version: databaseVersion)
                    }
                }
                else {
                    // Save the database version number to cache
                    CacheManager.putVersionIntoCache(version: databaseVersion)
                }

            }

        })

    }

    // MARK: - Helper Functions

    func parsePlacesFrom(placesDict:NSDictionary) -> [Place] {

        // Declare an array to store the parsed out places
        var allPlaces = [Place]()

        // Loop through all of the KVPs of the placesDict
        for (placeid, placedata) in placesDict {

            let placeDataDict = placedata as! NSDictionary

            // Create a Place object for each and add it to an array to be returned
            let place = Place()

            place.id = placeid as! String
            place.name = placeDataDict["name"] as! String
            place.addr = placeDataDict["address"] as! String
            place.lat = placeDataDict["lat"] as! Float
            place.long = placeDataDict["long"] as! Float
            place.type = PlaceType(rawValue: placeDataDict["type"] as! Int)!
            place.cellImageName = placeDataDict["imagesmall"] as! String

            place.createDate = placeDataDict["creationDate"] as! Int



            // Put this place object into an array for returning
            allPlaces += [place]
        }

        return allPlaces

    }

    func parseMetaFrom(metaDict:NSDictionary, place:Place) {

        place.desc = metaDict["desc"] as! String
        place.detailImageName = metaDict["imagebig"] as! String

    }

} // End class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here's what you gotta understand to start with:

This method `mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl)` is invoke over the *pin* you tap on, therefore you need to handle your logic from there.

Moving on, how would you do that when `MKAnnotationView` class is so limited and its main child (`annotation`) only provides you with the basics: pins' *coordinates*, *title* and *subtitle*... Easy, 2 options: you either make a custom class that inherits from it and you add your custom parameters in it and thus will be able to include relevant information you'll later use to every pin on the map **OR** (and I think this might be the one you choose since it's the *easiest* and more important, the one that produces less redundancy) you use coordinates from such point and later on make a cross-match from the selected's point coordinates and your places model. That would pretty much look something along the following lines:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    for p in places {
        let testLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(p.lat), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(p.long))
        if testLocation.latitude == view.annotation!.coordinate.latitude && testLocation.longitude == view.annotation!.coordinate.longitude {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "mapSegue", sender: p)
            break
        }
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let selectedPlace = sender as! Place //Careful with these force unwrapping in the future, I'm just using it here for simplicity but you should always double check them

    let detailModel = DetailModel()
    detailModel.place = selectedPlace

    let detailVC = segue.destination as! VenueDetailViewController
    detailVC.model = detailModel
}
```

As you can see, your *prepareForSegue* method pretty much stayed the same except that now it takes advantage of the sender parameter. You also should be careful when doing *segue.destination as! VenueDetailViewController* since, in the future if added more segues from this view, this may lead to crashes due to unexpected parameters sent from other classes.

Comment: I agree. Do you know how I can select the currently selected annotation?

Comment: You must work the logic inside the `mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl)`. I'd recommend obtaining the data there and only afterward calling `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` passing the info via _sender_ parameter. 

Like I said before: if you want more help from me, share more code or even better: share the entire repo and I'll take a look at it. I need more context.

Comment: Okay thanks, I've just updated my question to include the entire class plus my model and firebasemanager classes. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I see there's a lot of explaining to do. Let me edit my reply as well, I already did something like this in one of my previous projects so I know how to tackle this.

Comment: Done. I really hope this helps, have a happy new year.

Comment: Happy new year to you too! I've one issue on  `if p.coordinates == annotationView.annotation?.coordinate {` I'm getting an _Use of unresolved identifier 'annotationView'_ error. I've tried to do `let annotationView = MKAnnotationView()` but then get _Value of type 'Place' has no member 'coordinates'_ error. Not sure what I should do? Thanks Mauricio

Comment: Share the repo Ollie, I'm sure I can have you that ready in less than 10 minutes with the actual project.

Comment: I'll share the link now Thanks

Comment: Hmm I highly recommend you start using **Github** ASAP.

Comment: Okay would you like me to share this on Github? I can make an account

Comment: Sure, go ahead and do that. Then I'll make my contribution in it, I already solved the problem. My GitHub user is mchirino89

Comment: Thanks, I'm just creating it now.

Comment: I've just invited you to the github repo. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Done, I just committed the fix and updated the answer here. Don't forget to select my answer as the correct one please.